# How to map a mongodb comparison (e.g. $ne) inside a <Filter /> input

Tags: mongodb, feathersjs, react-admin

We are using some softDelete functionality for some of our mongodb collections (e.g. Users). The `deletedAT` prop of these collections is either null or a date. I need to use a filter input to show active (`deletedAt = null`) or inactive (e.g., `deletedAt = ISODate("2019-07-18T20:45:45.340Z"`)) collection items.

This works for a `<List /> filter` prop

```
<List title="User List" {...props} filter={{ deletedAt: null }} >
OR
<List title="User List" {...props} filter={{ deletedAt: { $ne: null } }} >
```

It actually also works for the `filterDefaultValues` prop

```
<List title="User List" {...props} filterDefaultValues={{ deletedAt: null }} >
OR
<List title="User List" {...props} filterDefaultValues={{ deletedAt: { $ne: null } }} >
```

However, I cannot make this work inside a `<Filter />` input e.g.,

```
export const UserFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <RadioButtonGroupInput source="deletedAt" choices={[
      { id: null, name: 'No' },
      { id: '$ne: null', name: 'Yes' },
    ]} alwaysOn />
  </Filter>

)
```

I get errors like this `Cast to date failed for value "$ne: null" at path "deletedAt" for model "User"` I've tried a number of different syntaxes, including trying to pass as objects, strings, etc with no luck. I suspect there is a difference in the request between a filter input and the `filter/filterDefaultValues` props of `<List />`. I'm hoping for a nudge in the right direction for creating a filter input that will handle mongodb comparison query operators?

Comment: What dataProvider are you using?
You need to have a specific data provider to support this kind of feature.

Comment: `ra-data-feathers` implemented as `<Admin loginPage={Login} authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={restClient(app, { id: '_id', usePatch: true })}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
<List title="User List" {...props} bulkActionButtons={<ConfirmBulkDelete />} {...paginationProps} filters={ <UserFilter /> } filterDefaultValues={{ deletedAt: { $type: 'null' } }} >
```

```
export const UserFilter = (props) => (
    <SelectInput label="Status" source="deletedAt[$type]" choices={[
      { id: 'null', name: 'Active' },
      { id: 'date', name: 'Archived' },
    ]} alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
)
```